# exceeding bounds of array in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have an assignmemnt for school, "Create a txt file with to fill a 5x8 array. I can read from the file fine, however, i keep getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' I know this means my index is exceeding my array bounds, however it should not be, at least that i can tell. any help would be appreciated. Code listed below in full...Error is coming from the private sub stansgrocery_load

```
Public Class StansGrocery
    Dim fileNameString As String = "C:\Users\lisht\Dropbox\Lish\Week 4\Stans\Grocerys.txt" 'Setting the preloaded location for my grocery.txt file
    Dim Food$(4, 7) 'setting the boundaries of the array
    Private Sub ReadFile(ByVal fileNameString As String, ByRef recordData() As String)
        fileNameString = "C:\Users\lisht\Dropbox\Lish\Week 4\Stans"
        Dim ptr, hell, cold As Int32
        itemsComboBox.Items.Clear()


        Dim currentRecordString, fileDataString As String
        Dim fileNumberInt As Integer = FreeFile()
        'Reads in a file with the first argument being it's location, and the second an array.  The  functions FileOpen, and Input use the filename to 
        'identify the file location, and filenumber, which is set by freefile, to identify the file. 
        Do


            Try
                FileOpen(1, fileNameString, OpenMode.Input)   'Opening the file
                hell = 0
            Catch ex As Exception
                hell = 1
                Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = fileNameString
                Me.OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
                fileNameString = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            End Try
        Loop Until hell = cold

        recordData = Split(fileDataString, "$$")                      'splitting the words for each deliminator of "$$"
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searchTextbox.TextChanged
        'This is the only way to close the program, by having the textbox check for change and seeing 
        '"zzz" the form will close. 
        If searchTextbox.Text = "zzz" Then Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StansGrocery_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'On load reads in the file with ReadFile Sub.  
        Dim originalFileName As String = "C:\Users\lisht\"
        Dim inventoryIn() As String
        'The first read in information is an empty string, so by Dimensioning i at 1 the first blank is always skipped, and also resets with each load.
        Dim i As Integer

        ReadFile(originalFileName, inventoryIn)

        For aisle = 0 To 4
            For item = 0 To 7

                Food(aisle, item) = inventoryIn(i)
                itemsComboBox.Items.Add(inventoryIn(i))
                i += 1

            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub InventoryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles itemsComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Loops through each array position and checks to see if the item is equal to the Combo box selected item.  Then shows its aisle and number,
        'by adding one to it's array index row and column.  If it is found it displays a message with the location.

        For aisle = 0 To 4
            For item = 0 To 7
                If Food(aisle, item) Is itemsComboBox.SelectedItem Then
                    Label1.Text = ("You will find " & Food(aisle, item) & " on aisle #" & aisle + 1 & ", item # " & item + 1)
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub searchTextBoxButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searchTextBoxButton.Click
        'Initiaties a search, and sets isFound to it's default "Item not found" message.
        Dim isFound As String = "The item you are searching for is not in the store"
        'Loops through each array position and checks to see if the item is equal to the read in text.  
        'Then shows its aisle and number, by adding one to it's array index row and column.  If it is found it displays a message with the location.
        For aisle = 0 To 4
            For Item = 0 To 7
                If Food(aisle, Item).ToLower = searchTextbox.Text.ToLower Then
                    'updates isFound if the item is found.
                    isFound = "You will find " & Food(aisle, Item) & " on aisle #" & aisle + 1 & ", item #" & Item + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        'Displays the location of the item, or the "Item not found message.
        Label1.Text = (isFound)

        searchTextbox.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You'll probably have a better chance of getting help if you provide a [repro] and the [exception details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: You have to post a sample of the text file here for us to see. Also, there are more modern ways of dealing with files. See [The File Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: potatoes, legumes, peas, corn, tomatoes, broccoli, cabbages, spinach
apples, bananas, oranges, avacados, peaches, pears, mangos, lemons
ground beef, chicken, sausages, hams, porks, roasts, bacon, fishes
vegetable oil, coconut oil, cooking spray, butters, margarines, lard, olive oil, peanut oil
milks, cheeses, yogurts, cream cheese, shredded cheese, string cheese, egg nog, chocolate milk

Comment: Your example file in the comment doesn't contain any `$$`. What does `fileDataString` contain when you call `Split`? Does `inventoryIn` have the amount of items that you expect?

Comment: @TylerLish - Please edit your question and show the input file between `<pre>` tags so we can see exactly what it looks like.

Comment: Haven't seen this is a while `Dim Food$(4, 7)`

Comment: Should we guess which line in private sub stansgrocery_load is causing the error?

Comment: `fileNameString` is declared and initialized as "C:\Users\lisht\Dropbox\Lish\Week 4\Stans\Grocerys.txt"

Then we have another `fileNameString` as an argument of `ReadFile` which is passed "C:\Users\lisht\". The first line of the ReadFile method assigns "C:\Users\lisht\Dropbox\Lish\Week 4\Stans" Why bother passing in a value if you are immediately going to change it. Also it is very bad practice to have a local variable and a class level variable with the same name.

Comment: Moving on with `ReadFile` You declar a variable ptr which is never used. Next you inexplicably clear a combo box.
Again a variable `currentRecordString` that is never used. You get a file number but hard code 1 where it should be used. Actually file io is now handled by the .net File class. You do an interesting dance catching errors and looping but let's assume the file opened successfully. The loop ends and you attempt to split an empty string. Nothing has ever been assigned to `fileDataString` so, splitting it is not possible. Even with the old VB6 Strings.Spilt method.

Comment: Passing the declared but not instantiated `inventoryIn` ByRef might work if something was assigned to it in the ReadFile method but it wasn't. As soon as you try to access `inventoryIn(i)` you are out of luck. `inventoryIn(i) has never been assigned a value so, it can't be accessed.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger to see where its behavior differs from your expectations?